# Generating a DML statements(insert) from the Domain class in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

I have a requirement where i need to write a set of insert statements into a file with values which needs to taken from the list of a domain classes.

So, instead of preparing a string that consists of an insert statement with values taken from the each domain in the list and writing this to a file, is there a way where we can get these required insert statements with values from the domain class itself as the domain class consists of all the values for its properties and has the mappings.
So that we just write those insert statements to file.

Thanks,
Pavan

Answer (score 0):

Correct If I am wrong, if you have domain classes that means your data exist in the database then wouldn't it better to take database dump which includes insert statements and remove all create table statements from there?
To create database dump you can follow this [blog](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/04/23/592/).

Comment: No, actually i have prepared a list of domain classes manually which needs to be inserted to database. These data was not there in the database.